# Packages have unmet dependencies - GUI gone and stuck in tty1

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Installed [this DisplayLink driver](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) via APT, and after the reboot, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS goes into tty1.

What I tried:

- sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
- sudo apt -f install
- sudo apt update --fix-missing

Full error message and list of packages:
[image]

Error Message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies

How to get the GUI back?

Comment: You must have added repositories/PPAs to your system that contain software which is incompatible with the basic Ubuntu system.  With the information  given, all anyone can say is, remove those repositories and the software you installed from them.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` before installing? If not, then your system will think that older versions are required when newer versions are now required that the old versions are no longer available. But the system is trying to install the newest available version and your system still hasn't updated the package list (first command, `sudo apt update`) so it still thinks the older version is the one it needs and so it's confused.

Comment: It appears that's the problem. Because it's saying older versions are required but it's downloading newer versions instead. This is because updates are available that your system is unaware about. Run `sudo apt update` and then proceed. It's also recommended you run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` as well to actually apply any available updates. After the update command, you can either try your install command again, or if that doesn't work, then  `sudo apt -f install` and if that doesn't fix it, then install the dependencies one by one: `sudo apt install pipewire` etc., and then try again.

Comment: From what I can see here in your error message, the fact that you added an additional repository is only coincidental to the problem and it appears the only problem is that the package list is out of date. If no other problems pop up, then the display port repo appears to be unrelated and is probably okay to keep.